# POST não está pegando os dados do input que está no javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Bom, ao clicar no botão "Programar Notícia" aparece um input para por data e hora... Mas ao enviar o "formulário", o input que está dentro do javascript não está recebendo os dados, os normais já estão... Engraçado que eu usei este código ontem e estava funcionando

```
       } elseif($do == "add"){

        $editor_mode = true;

        if($_POST['submit']){

            if($_POST['postdate']){
            $status = "Inativo";
            $programada = "sim";
            }else{
            $status = $_POST['status'];
            $programada = "não";
            }
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO cms_news (title,image,longstory,shortstory,published,author,promo,categoria,status,postdate,posthora,programada) VALUES ('".$_POST['title']."','".$_POST['image']."','".$_POST['longstory']."','".$_POST['shortstory']."','".time()."','".$_POST['author']."','".$_POST['promo']."','".$_POST['categoria']."','".$status."','".$_POST['postdate']."','".$_POST['posthora']."','".$programada."')") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO stafflogs (action,message,note,userid,targetid,timestamp) VALUES ('Notícias','Publicou uma notícia','news.php','".$my_id."','".$key."','".$date_full."')") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<script>alert('Registro inserido com sucesso')</script>";
        $editor_mode = false;   
    }
    }
    ?>
<fieldset><legend><?php echo $pagename; ?></legend>

   <table width="100%" style="float:right;border:0px">
   <form action='<?php echo $adminpath; ?>/index/p/news&do=add' method='post' name='theAdminForm' id='theAdminForm'>
                    <tr>
          <div class="input_field">
           <div style="margin-left:69px;">
          <label for="num"><b>Titulo</b>:</label>
            <input required="required" type="text" name="title" class="bigfield">
            </div>
        </div>
            </tr>

                                <tr>
          <div class="input_field">
           <div style="margin-left:69px;">
          <label for="num"><b>Resumo</b>:</label>
            <input required="required" type="text" name="shortstory" class="bigfield">
            </div>
        </div>
            </tr>

                    <tr>
          <div class="input_field">
           <div style="margin-left:69px;">
          <label for="num"><b>Top Story</b>:</label>
            <input required="required" type="text" name="image" class="bigfield"><div style="margin-left:29px;"><i>Utilizar o link da imagem, preferêncialmente do Imgur. Não é permitido dos servidores da Sulake.</i><div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </tr>


 <tr>
          <div class="input_field">
           <div style="margin-left:69px;">
          <label for="num"><b>Autor</b>:</label>
            <input required="required" type="text" name="author" class="bigfield">
            </div>
        </div>
            </tr>


                                            <tr>
          <div class="input_field">
           <div style="margin-left:69px;">
          <label for="num"><b>Categoria</b>:</label>
            <select required="required" name="categoria" style="margin-top:05px;">

                        <option value="" id="categoria">Selecione</option>

                    <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cms_news_cat ORDER BY ID";
$query1 = mysql_query ($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($manu = mysql_fetch_array ($query1)){
?>

<option value="<?php echo $manu['id']; ?>"><?php echo $manu['nome']; ?></option><?php } ?></select>
<div style="margin-top:5px;"></div>

        </div>
            </tr>


                                                <tr>
          <div class="input_field">
           <div style="margin-left:69px">
          <label for="num"><b>Tipo</b>:</label>
            <select required="required" name="promo" style="margin-top:05px;">

           <option value="" id="tipo">Selecione</option>

<option value="Sem Promoção">Não especificar</option><option value="Promoção Aberta">Promoção Aberta</option><option value="Promoção Encerrada">Promoção Encerrada</option></select>
<div style="margin-top:5px;"></div>

        </div>
            </tr>

                                                            <tr>
          <div class="input_field">
           <div style="margin-left:69px;">
          <label for="num"><b>Status</b>:</label>
            <select required="required" name="status" style="margin-top:05px;">

           <option value="" id="tipo">Selecione</option>

<option value="Ativo">Ativo</option><option value="Rascunho">Rascunho</option><option value="Inativo">Inativo</option></select>
<div style="margin-top:5px;"></div>

        </div>
            </tr>

  <div id="inputprogram"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
function insereInput() {
  if ( document.getElementById('botao').innerHTML == 'Programar Notícia' ) {
    // modificar texto do botão:
    document.getElementById('botao').innerHTML = 'Não Programar Notícia';
    // ou se usares <input type="button"> em vez do elemento <button> simplesmente muda innerHTML para value
    document.getElementById('inputprogram').innerHTML = '<tr> <div class="input_field"><div style="margin-left:69px;"><label for="textfild"><b>Postar em</b>:</label><input required="required" type="text" name="postdate" class="smallfield">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input required="required" type="text" name="posthora" size="03"><div style="margin-left:115px;"><i> Dia/Mês/Ano &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Hora:Minuto</i></div></div></div> </tr>';
  } else {
    // modificar texto do botão de volta para o padrão:
    document.getElementById('botao').innerHTML = 'Programar Notícia';
    document.getElementById('inputprogram').innerHTML = '';
  }
  document.querySelector("form").submit();
}
</script>

    <tr>
          <div class="input_field">
         <div style="margin-left:69px;">
          <label for="num"><b>Notícia</b>:</label>
          </div>
            <br><br><textarea name="longstory" id="story" class="ckeditor"></textarea></td>
            </div>
            </tr>

           <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Inserir Registro" />
       <button class="submit" type="button" id="botao" onclick="insereInput()">Programar Notícia</button>
            </form> 
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando 2 botões como `submit`.

Deixe apenas o segundo como `type="button"` para *inserir*/*remover* os campos:

```js
function insereInput() {
  if ( document.getElementById('botao').innerHTML == 'Programar Notícia' ) {
    // modificar texto do botão:
    document.getElementById('botao').innerHTML = 'Não Programar Notícia';
    // ou se usares <input type="button"> em vez do elemento <button> simplesmente muda innerHTML para value
    document.getElementById('inputprogram').innerHTML = '<tr> <div class="input_field"><div style="margin-left:69px;"><label for="textfild"><b>Postar em</b>:</label><input required="required" type="text" name="postdate" class="smallfield">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input required="required" type="text" name="posthora" size="03"><div style="margin-left:115px;"><i> Dia/Mês/Ano &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Hora:Minuto</i></div></div></div> </tr>';
  } else{
    // modificar texto do botão de volta para o padrão:
    document.getElementById('botao').innerHTML = 'Programar Notícia';
    document.getElementById('inputprogram').innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="teste.php">
   <div id="inputprogram"></div>
   <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Inserir Registro" />
   <button class="submit" type="button" id="botao" onclick="insereInput()">Programar Notícia</button>
</form>
```

### Edit

Além das correções acima, é preciso colocar toda a `<table>` dentro do `<form>` para que ele reconheça os campos adicionados de forma dinâmica:

```
<form .....>
  <table ...>
  ...
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, os dados do campo que está no javascript estão chegando em branco no POST

Comment: Ele pega todos os campos, somente o campo que ta no javascript ele não pega, não entendo isto...

Comment: @CarlosG Tô vendo aqui pra vc..

Comment: @CarlosG Atualizei a resposta com um Edit. Faça as alterações e teste aí.

Comment: Cara, você é demais... 4 horas quebrando cabeça aqui, por que antes este código funcionava, eu devo ter acabado trocando estes negócios, resolveu aqui, nunca podia imaginar que a table iria interferir, obrigado!